# SharePoint App download file from url

Tags: development, 2013, sharepoint-addin, download

I have a SharePoint 2013 app where I want to download a file.
in the web project I get the url from a file in SharePoint and I want to download it using the following code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData(docUrl);
FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\local\");
file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```

But i get an error 401: Unauthorized

How can I download the file from SharePoint in the web project with the URL of the file?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Apps don't have access to the file system directly.  You could download a file and save it to a SharePoint library, but you wouldn't be able to save it directly to the local file system.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268593.aspx for some considerations between a SharePoint App and a SharePoint Farm Solution.